# JSF faces config file outside WEB-INF?

Tags: java, jsf, web-inf, faces-config

When creating multiple faces config files, it is correct to have the faces-config.xml outside of WEB-INF? The JSF spec does not seem to be very clear about this (Section 10.1.3)

If yes, how should this faces-config.xml be declared in web.xml? the paths generated by IDE's (like Eclipse/JDev) generally use something like:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config1.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now, if my faces-config.xml is outside WEB-INF -- is it correct to declare the param-value as something like "/WebContent/WEB-INF/faces-config2.xml"?

Answer (score 7):

It is possible, but not recommended. The reason you put configuration files under WEB-INF is that the server knows not to serve these files - you have your code, database configuration and other sensitive stuff there.

You cannot use "/WebContent/WEB-INF/faces-config2.xml" - AFAIK "WebContent" is eclipse specific. have the config files names to be absolute inside the WAR. It means that they will always begin with "/WEB-INF/".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in David's answer, it's not recommended to put the config files outside of the WEB-INF directory. However, if you're looking for ways to organise your project, you might try creating a new subdirectory *under* WEB-INF.

For example, when I'm dealing with lots of faces-config files, I'll create a directory `/WEB-INF/config` and put the faces-config files in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing them from the web.xml, then the file needs to be in the war at runtime. There are other ways that the container can discover faces-config.xml resources.

**10.4.2**
At application startup time, before any requests are processed, the JSF implementation must
process zero or more application configuration resources, located according to the following
algorithm:

- Search for all resources named “META-INF/faces-config.xml” in the
  ServletContext resource paths for this web application, and load each as a JSF
  configuration resource (in reverse order of the order in which they are returned by
  getResources() on the current Thread’s ContextClassLoader).
- Check for the existence of a context initialization parameter named
  javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES. If it exists, treat it as a comma-delimited list of
  context relative resource paths (starting with a “/”), and load each of the specfied
  resources.
- Check for the existence of a web application configuration resource named “/WEBINF/
  faces-config.xml”, and load it if the resource exists.