# Managed beans in xsp-config files

Tags: xpages

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to keep managed beans in separate .xsp-config  configuration files?
And if yes than how to do this? I have tried and it only worked if I put them into  faces-config.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Managed beans must be defined in the faces-config.xml file.

For a good reference on all the different options within faces-config and xsp-config take a look at [this website](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_configuration_file_format). It describes the format of pretty much everything you might ever want to add to a faces-config or xsp-config and a brief description of the options.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to split your bean definitions into multiple configuration files, you'll need to create an OSGi plugin. XSP libraries can contain more than one faces-config file (and you can name them whatever you want, because you specify in the library class which XML files contain faces-config definitions). But in an NSF, you're limited to just the auto-generated faces-config.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know they have to be in the faces-config.xml

Answer (score 0):

faces-config is a JSF implementation, you should check out the JSF specification for this, there are even some good post in this forum like this one:
[JSF faces config file outside WEB-INF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365512/jsf-faces-config-file-outside-web-inf)