# Faces-config .xml in JSF, how to registered

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Let we have some `faces-config.xml`. The code snippet is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"> 
   ...
</faces-config>
```

From what `JSF` runtime environment does know that `faces-config.xml` is the `web-app` configuration file.

Can we rename `faces-config.xml` to another?

At what phases of application lifecycle `faces-config.xml` is parsing?

Comment: faces-config is for global configurations of your applications. web.xml is the web app configuraition file. The file is parsed during application startup. Go through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365512/jsf-faces-config-file-outside-web-inf
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583038/what-is-the-use-of-faces-config-xml-in-jsf-2

Comment: 1 `web.xml` per web application project, 0 `faces-config.xml` in principle per JSF 2.x environment project.